# How to start day-trading? Any advice about software for beginner?

Tags: trading, software, day-trading

I want to start day trading, but I am beginner and I need help.
Is there some online tutorial? I want to start with just 1000 dollar.
Is it enought? I find ninja trader software. Is it good? Or do you
know any better software for beginner?

Comment: Don't.  Go to a casino instead.  At least you'll get free drinks while your money lasts.

Comment: You will get eaten alive by transaction costs if you trade with $1000.  You will be completely out of money after 100-200 trades.  And that's if they let you make an account with only 1k.  So instead, maybe you should consider putting your entire life savings in....

Comment: On the other hand, your losses are limited to $1,000 so it's better starting with $1,000 and ending up broken than to start with $5,000 and ending up broke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe learn a bit more before plunging in with your own money, buy some good books on the subject and on technical analysis. Open up a virtual account and test your strategies first, develop a trading plan and include risk management in it, think about what the worst case scenario will be on each trade. Learn about position sizing and where to place your stop losses. A good book to start with is "Trade your way to Financial Freedom" by Van Tharp.

$1000 is a bit small to start even if you use margin, because one bad trade can wipe you out, or even worse, you could lose even more than your $1000 if using margin whilst you don't know what you are doing. Whilst you are learning about trading and technical analysis save up some more money. I would use a minimum of $5000 and preferably over $10000 if using margin and at least $20000 without margin.

Also one other thing, day trading means you will need to spend most of your day in front of your screen, will this interfere with your day job and will you be getting enough sleep? You need to be trading with a clear mind. There are alternatives to day trading, position trading and swing trading to name 2. You will be in a position from a couple of days to a couple of weeks in these type of trading and you won't have to be in front of your screen all day. You can spend one or two hours per day after market close to place new orders and manage existing ones, that way it won't interfere with your day job or other daily activities you do.

Comment: No problem, there is nothing wrong in taking up day trading, and one can be successful at it, but you do need to think about what you are getting in for and if it is right for you, what is required and the planning required to be successful. Don't listen to those that say it is just gambling, because buy and hold can also be gambling. If you don't have a plan for what you are doing, when it comes to investing, in my opinion it is gambling.

Comment: I just read same thing in Day Trainding For Dummies. I think is good book for start. First I need more informations and then I will setup demo account and if it will be still interesting for me, than I will use real money.

Comment: @Alex - also by setting up a demo account you can see how much money you will actually need if you plan to take it up and how much day you will need to spend each day. It's not for everybody but it may be for you, and a demo account is good to try out all these things on, as well as to develop a trading plan and test your strategies on.

Answer (score 4):

$1000 is certainly not enough cash to begin to day trade with.  Brokerage will eat your bankroll, even if you do manage to do well.  If you can get cheap brokerage (say $5, which is lower than any I've seen) you're still wasting 1% of your bankroll every time you trade in and out.  Given that on a good day you might make 2-3% on your day trades and on a bad day lose 2-3%, what you're really doing is paying the brokerage company to have some fun on the market.

Successful day trading is mostly a myth peddled by people with books to sell.  You're actually much better off in the long run just sticking your money in an index fund.

Or betting it all on black.

Comment: FYI, eOption offers $3 trades and $0.10 option contracts. (Not affiliated, just saw you mention you hadn't seen lower than $5.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend paper trading with stocktrak.com, or with an IB paper trading account.  It's not perfect, but you can see how the process works.  I think day trading (even with huge amounts of money) is a terrible idea, but you can (and should) learn how to trade over longer time frames (weeks, months, or years), or learn that index funds are better.  These index funds beat active managers (who typically have years of experience) 80% of the time.  I would also learn about fundamental analysis, and how to understand company financials....